# Codigniter output field with variable

Tags: codeigniter, output

I want to ouput a field of my table, but where the fieldname contains a variable from the surrounded foreach.

This seems to give an error..
Any solution?

```
<? foreach ($languages as $language): ?>
    <? foreach ($accomodations as $accomodation): ?>
        <?= $accomodation->about_$language->language ?>
    <? endforeach ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution myself.

```
<? foreach ($languages as $language): ?>
    <? foreach ($accomodations as $accomodation): ?>
        <? $field = 'about_'.$language->language ?>
        <?= $accomodation->$field?>
    <? endforeach ?>
<? endforeach ?>
```